# Javascript: Please explain what this for loop is doing

Tags: javascript

Learning javascript and have come across something I cant figure out. Open devtools and go to your console

```
countries = ['Germany', 'Argentina', 'Brazil', 'Netherlands'];

for (country in countries[1]) {
  console.log(country); //or console.log(countries)
};
```

I predicted it would either
A: Only run the first index outputting "Argentina" or
B: Start from the 1st index to the end.

Instead it runs 9 times, indexing the entire array. Why is it running 9 times, and is there a reason this should ever be used or did I just run into something pretty useless?

Comment: extend your code to log both, *key* AND *value*: `console.log('key:', country, 'value:', countries[1][country]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A for .. in loop means to loop over the properties of an object.

`countries[1]` is a string. Ergo

```
for (country in countries[1])
```

means to loop over the properties of a string object, assigning the property name to `country`. In javascript, array-like things are just objects whose properties happen to be numerical. And so `country` assumes the numbers `0`, `1`, `2`, etc. It loops 9 times because 'Argentina' has nine letters.

If you were then to access in the loop:

```
countries[1][country]
```

Each iteration would give you a character in the sequence `A`, `r`, `g`, `e`, `n`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is looping through the characters (or rather, their indices) in the string `'Argentina'`.

The for...in loop is one of the parts of JavaScript that you should really read up on before you start using it in production code. It often doesn't do what you might expect, because it will iterate over all enumerable properties of an object (which may belong to the object's prototype chain, instead of just the object itself).

You probably want a regular old for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
  console.log(countries[i]);
}
```

If you are in an environment where you can use ES6 (such as node.js or transpiling with babel/typescript), you can use a for...of loop:

```
for (const country of countries) {
  console.log(country);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for...in returns the key of what you're iterating through.

for...of returns the value of each element of the container you're iterating through.

If you used for...of it would print out Argentina.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looping over `countries[1]`, it will loop over the characters in the string `'Argentina'`. Since `'Argentina'` has nine letters, the loop will run nine times.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating through country[1], which is 'Argentina' in this case. 
The var 'country''s value is changed on each iteration to the index it is looking at in the string country[1]
To best illustrate this you can try this script which will print out each letter of Argentina, as well as the methods available via the string prototype.

```
countries = ['Germany', 'Argentina', 'Brazil', 'Netherlands'];

for (country in countries[1]) {
 console.log(countries[1][country]); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can have array inside array. So in your code, you're asking for loop to iterate the array present on `[1]` index of `countries[]` array.

Now in your array, a string is present at index `[1]`. So Js is breaking it into a character array and iterating it.

Answer (score 0):

the `for in` statemant accept an `Object` as second argument after `in`. 
if you pass an array it will forced to an `Object`. The first argument is **not** the value but the **key**. So 'argentina' is probably forced to be an Object like:

```
{0:'a',1:'r',2:'g',3:'e',4:'n',5:'t',6:'i',7:'n',8:'a'}
```

So if you try `console.log(countries[country]);` it will log characters.

It's pretty useless. JS has a bunch of things pretty useless, then it has a good part. Try to use the good one.